# More admins in Google+ Event

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-events

How can I make some guests of my event able to change the event?

I would expect an answer in [G+ Events help](http://support.google.com/plus/bin/answer.py?hl=cs&answer=2612999&topic=2612996&ctx=topic), but there's nothing about this topic.

Comment: It doesn't look like there is. The closest thing is to allow invitees to invite other people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google+ does not have the ability to allow guests to edit an Event as of Feb 2014. One alternative is to

1. Create a Google+ Page
2. Invite Event managers/administrators to become Manager of your Page
3. All Google+ Page managers will automatically have the permissions to edit an Event

[image: Google+ Page Managers]

Comment: I like what you are suggesting, but it's not what i was asking for :(